# Crap4j libClassPath as path reference

Tags: java, ant, utility

I am trying to use CRAP4J utility to analyse my code and I am stuck while passing the classpath. My ant task look like as follows;

```
<target name="run-crap-4j" unless="crap-4j-finishes" depends="init" description="This target will run crap-4j for analysis." >
    <crap4j projectdir="${basedir}" outputDir="${build.dir}${file.separator}reports${file.separator}crap4j"
            dontTest="false" debug="false">
        <srces>
            <pathElement location="${base.dir}${file.separator}src" />
        </srces>        
        <classes>
            <pathElement location="${build.dir}${file.separator}classes" />
        </classes>
        <testClasses>
            <pathElement location="${build.dir}${file.separator}testclasses" />
        </testClasses>

        <libClasspath>
            <path refid="${project.classpath}" />
            <path refid="${test.classpath}" />
        </libClasspath>
    </crap4j>
    <property name="crap-4j-finishes" value="true"/>
</target>
```

When I run my target it gives me following error;

```
run-crap-4j:
Unresolvable reference ${project.classpath} might be a misuse of property expansion syntax.

BUILD FAILED
C:\RTC\TechDev\SoaFramework\build.xml:931: Reference ${project.classpath} not found.
```

According to CRAP4J documentation in  I should be passing the fileset but the problem is that I do not have my dependencies at one location, they are scattered all over. Could you please help me sort this problem or give me suggestion on how to proceed now?

Thanks

--

Sjunejo

Comment: I have updated my script and now I am copying all my files locally into project lib directory and CRAP4J is going forward but its failing now on following;
         [echo] CRAP4J_HOME = C:\Utils\crap4j
   [crap4j] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot figure out Crap4j Home!!
   [crap4j]     at org.crap4j.Main.getCrap4jHomeFromClass(Main.java:126)

The CRAP4J_HOME is set correctly in my environment!

Comment: please use the edit function (edit button below the question) for updates

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its a bug in CRAP4J. Refer following link for solution;

http://code.google.com/p/crap4j/issues/detail?id=12

Thanks,

--

SJunejo